# Scheme - have a function return a function

Tags: function, functional-programming, lisp, scheme, currying

I want to use this code in the following way:
if I enter:

```
((function1 5) 2)
```

where function1 executes its procedure based off the `5`, and returns a `function2` that executes something based on the `2`. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
(define (multiplyBy n) (lambda (x) (* n x)))
((multiplyBy 5) 2)
```

I believe will do what you're trying to do.

Comment: What is this technique called? Could you point me to where it's described in [R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/final/r6rs.pdf)? I searched for "higher-order functions" and "curried functions" (which is how I've heard this described) but I couldn't find that language used in the document.

Comment: I'm not sure what the formal name of it is -- it's more or less an extension of what is done in sections `11.2.1` and `11.4.2`.  `(define)` [3rd form] assigns some formals and a body to a variable name; the body happens to be a lambda expression returning a function.  The lambda part specifies that "The environment in effect when the lambda expression is evaluated is remembered as part of the procedure".  This means that when executed, first the `define`'d variable is evaluated with its arguments, which passes them into the lamba's environment (which is saved in the resulting procedure).

Answer (score 1):

Continuing with @zebediah49's example, here's another way to do it:

```
(define (multiplyBy n) ((curry *) n))
((multiplyBy 5) 2)
> 10
```

In general, for a two-argument function (the above example looks a bit different because `*` is a one-or-more argument function):

```
(define (function1 arg0) (curry <function2, receives arg1> arg0))
```

Quoting the documentation of the [`curry`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html) procedure:

> Returns a procedure that is a curried version of `proc`. When the resulting procedure is first applied, unless it is given the maximum number of arguments that it can accept, the result is a procedure to accept additional arguments

Basically, you're being asked to implement [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). Quoting the wikipedia article:

> In mathematics and computer science, currying is the technique of transforming a function that takes multiple arguments (or an n-tuple of arguments) in such a way that it can be called as a chain of functions each with a single argument (partial application). It was originated by Moses Schönfinkel and later re-discovered by Haskell Curry. Because of this, some say it would be more correct to name it schönfinkeling.

Notice that all these are equivalent:

```
(define ((function1 arg0) arg1) <body>)
(define (function1 arg0) (lambda (arg1) <body>))
(define (function1 arg0) (curry <function2, receives arg1> arg0))
(define (function1 arg0) (define (function2 arg1) <body>) function2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I asked around, and what I found out is that you can define a function like this:

`(define ((function1 arg0) arg1) (;procedure here...))`

This is what I wanted. I guess it wasn't really getting a function to return a procedure after all... :/ Thanks for all the help though! :)

Comment: Actually, what you've written *is* a function that returns a function. Try calling your function1 with just 1 argument. You should see that you get back... a function! So in fact, there are *many* ways to return functions from functions. See my answer below for yet another way...

Comment: `(define ((function1 arg0) arg1) <body>)` is syntactic sugar for `(define (function1 arg0) (lambda (arg1) <body>))`, both versions are the same under the hood

Comment: I guess this was the same as zebediah's answer, but like Oscar said, is different syntactically. Thanks for all the help, everyone! :)

Answer (score 0):

Many of these answers correctly show different ways of returning functions from functions. More generally, what you're doing is called Currying. More specifically, "currying" refers to the process of transforming a function that takes n arguments into one that takes one argument and returns a new function that takes n-1 arguments.

Here's the style that looks the nicest to me, for a beginning student:

```
#lang racket

;; a curried function that multiplies two numbers
(define (function1 arg0)
  (define (function2 arg1) 
    (* arg0 arg1))
  function2)
```

This function accepts an argument (arg0), defines a new function of one argument (arg1) that multiplies arg0 and arg1, and then returns it.

This one isn't as short as the one using lambda, but when you're starting out, lambda can seem like just one more weird thing that doesn't make sense.